# LLVM With Haskell, Strange Linker Error

Tags: macos, haskell, dll, linker, llvm

I just installed LLVM (3.0) successfully, and got the Hackage bindings (3.0.0.0). However when I try to use it, I get the following linker error:

> Loading package llvm-base-3.0.0.0 ... can't load .so/.DLL for:  (dlopen(lib.dylib, 9): image not found)

There is no name after "for: ", which makes this frustrating, because I don't know what it can't find. I know there isn't much information to go on, but does anyone have any idea why this could be happening?

I am running Mac OS X, in case it matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bug in the llvm bindings installer. I had it patched locally and just sent a [pull request](https://github.com/bos/llvm/pull/32) to bos, hopefully it will get merged soon.

To fix your problem without the patch, find the llvm-base package config file. Mine is located here:

`~/.ghc/x86_64-darwin-7.4.1/package.conf.d/llvm-base-3.0.0.0-*.conf`

Locate this line and delete it:
`extra-ghci-libraries: ""`

Then run: `ghc-pkg recache --user`

Comment: Thanks, will try it now. I suspected it was just an empty string thing, because of the lack of library name, but I didn't know where to look for it and even if I did, I didn't want to mess with anything without knowing what I was doing.